# Cannot compute Count for a data source that does not implement ICollection.

Tags: c#, repeater, paging

Here is my code

```
 var q = from a in bh
                join b in hr on a.HotelCode equals b.hotelCode
                select new
        {
            a.HotelCode,
            a.ImageURL_Text,
            a.HotelName,
            a.StarRating,    
            a.HotelAddress,
            a.Destination,
            a.Country,
            a.HotelInfo,
            a.Latitude,
            a.Longitude,
            b.totalPrice,
            b.totalPriceSpecified,
            b.totalSalePrice,
            b.totalSalePriceSpecified,
            b.rooms

    };

        //rptHotels.DataSource = getres.availableHotels;

        PagedDataSource objPds = new PagedDataSource();
        objPds.DataSource = q;
        objPds.AllowPaging = true;
        objPds.PageSize = 10;// Convert.ToInt32(ddlPageNo.SelectedValue);

        objPds.CurrentPageIndex = CurrentPage;

        lblCurrentPage.Text = "Page: " + (CurrentPage + 1).ToString() + " of "
           + objPds.PageCount.ToString();

        // Disable Prev or Next buttons if necessary
        cmdPrev.Enabled = !objPds.IsFirstPage;
        cmdNext.Enabled = !objPds.IsLastPage;

        rptHotels.DataSource = objPds;
        rptHotels.DataBind();
```

error has self explanation but not getting the way to solve this error ......

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use ToArray():

```
objPds.DataSource = q.ToArray();
```

Comment: any idea to sort this array based on hotelName,star rating ?

Comment: Before "select new" add "order by a.HotelName, a.StarRating"